# "Red or blue" clicking game score counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to make a game where there is a big square that appears red or blue and the user has to click "v" or "b" accordingly. I have eventually completed this part however in an unsatisfying and unprofessional way (if you can guide me to a better method that would be great as well) you can see what i have done so far here: http://www.ysk.co.za/red-blue/

My problem with this is I have no way to keep a score or elapsed time

My javascript is:

```
function key(e){
    var code=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    var random = Math.random();
    if (random <= 0.5) {
        $("#RedBlue").css("background-color","red")
    } else {
        $("#RedBlue").css("background-color","blue")
    }

    if (code === 86) {
        $("#red").css("background","#ff4e00");
        setTimeout(function(){$("#red").css("background-color","red")},500);
        var color ="rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    } else if (code === 66) {
        $("#blue").css("background-color","#006bff");
        setTimeout(function(){$("#blue").css("background-color","blue")},500);
        color = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
    }


        var i = 0;
        if ($("#RedBlue").css("background-color") != color) {
            alert("you lost, you got a total of: "+i+"! click ok to restart");
            document.location.reload(true);
        } else if ($("#RedBlue").css("background-color") == color) {
            $("#score").prepend("Correct<br>");
            i+=200;
        }


}
```

My HTML is:

```
<h1>Red or blue</h1>
<h3>Concentration game</h3>
<div id="RedBlue"></div>
<div id="red" style="background:red;"></div>
<div id="blue" style="background:blue;"></div><div class="clear"></div>
Click "v" if the big square is red and "b" if the big square is blue<br>
<input type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" onkeyup="key(event); this.select()" />
<div id="score"></div>
```

I have tried to use `var i` to be a counter for every time the user is correct and display that number when they are wrong, however "i" does not increment.

What would be the best method to keep score

PS: eventually I would like the score keeping method to be a rate of clicks per second. Which would be basic maths once I am able to tally the clicks and seconds - "clicks divided by seconds"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `var i = 0` outside of your function.

If you put this in your function, it will always be 0 when user makes the bad choice.

To get the number of clicks by second, you can do

```
var i = 0;
//add a click counter (you could also use i, but as you increment it by 200...)
var click = 0;
//startTime
var startTime =new Date().getTime() / 1000; //this will count the time as soon as page is loaded. You may prefer to start after first click.

    function key(e){
        click +=1;
        var code=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
        var random = Math.random();
        if (random <= 0.5) {
            $("#RedBlue").css("background-color","red")
        } else {
            $("#RedBlue").css("background-color","blue")
        }

        if (code === 86) {
            $("#red").css("background","#ff4e00");
            setTimeout(function(){$("#red").css("background-color","red")},500);
            var color ="rgb(255, 0, 0)";
        } else if (code === 66) {
            $("#blue").css("background-color","#006bff");
            setTimeout(function(){$("#blue").css("background-color","blue")},500);
            color = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
        }



            if ($("#RedBlue").css("background-color") != color) {
                //calculate the elapsed time  = now - startTime
                var timeElapsed =(new Date().getTime() / 1000) -startTime;
                alert("you lost, you got a total of: "+i+"! click ok to restart");
                //simple click / second calculation
                alert('nb of clicks / seconds : ' + click / timeElapsed);
                alert('total time in seconds : ' + timeElapsed);
                document.location.reload(true);
            } else if ($("#RedBlue").css("background-color") == color) {
                $("#score").prepend("Correct<br>");
                i+=200;
            }
    }
```

**EDIT**

To start "timer" after first key pressed :

```
var i = 0; 
var click = 0;
var startTime;

function key(e) {
if (click == 0) startTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
click +=1;
//etc.
}
```

see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2rHx/2/)

Comment: Added click per second (really basic : you could have a start button to reset i to 0 and time to new starttime, to be able to play multiple times and have correct values).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, As you added as a comment; it would be great to count the time from the first click, would this be possible? I have played around with some if statements but cant seem to figure it out